# displaying column based on value of another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a table like this:

```
Parent | Child
1      | 11
11     | 12
11     | 13
12     | 14
12     | 14
```

If pass 1, it should return all the ‘1’ children’s: 11, 12, 13, 14

Comment: this is the classic transitive closure problem

Comment: Is this an HTML, SQL, Excel, or wooden table?

Comment: Just guessing here but if this is by any chance a homework question then you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at recursive queries using CTE.
Links about the topic:

- [Simple example of recursive CTE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/)
- [Example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Test data
declare @T table (ParentID int, ChildID int)
insert into @T values(1,       11)
insert into @T values(11,      12)
insert into @T values(11,      13)
insert into @T values(12,      14)
insert into @T values(12,      14)

-- ID to search for
declare @ParentID int = 1

-- Recorsive cte
;with cte as
(
  select T.*
  from @T as T
  where T.ParentID = @ParentID
  union all
  select T.*
  from cte as C
    inner join @T as T
      on C.ChildID = T.ParentID
)
select distinct ChildID
from cte
```

Result

```
ChildID
-------
11
12
13
14
```